# How to Prevent User From Submitting Property Or View His Posted Properties Before Login in wordpress?

Tags: plugins

Hello I Want Real Estate Website to develop like 99acres.com in wordpress.Now I Want User To Compulsory Login Before Posting /submitting property to site or to view his posted properties  he must be logged in.Is There Any wordpress Plugin That Provides such functionality?

Comment: Specific plugin recommendations are off-topic here, but yes, if you search you'll easily find a number of membership plugins that can restrict access to content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has function to check whether user is logged in or not

```
is_user_logged_in(){
  /**Your code goes here**/
}
```

wrap your code inside this to allow only logged in users the access